# Dataframe values pre-processing - readexcel drop apostrophe in values during importing or other ways to convert string to int values after importing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file with the data format below to import in dataframe.

My current code allows me to extract the exact rows as show in the picture into the dataframe.

```
df_gdp = pd.read_excel (open(gdp_path,'rb'), sheet_name='T2', skiprows= 5, skipfooter= 29)
```

Below is the data in excel:
[image]

Below is my dataframe output:
[image]

Problem: The values shown above are imported as string with the apostrophe at the beginning and ending not being shown.

When I tried to convert values to int using the below methods, it doesn't work.

```
df_gdp.iloc[1:, 1] = df_gdp.iloc[1:, 0].str.replace("'", "").astype(float)

or

b1 = df_gdp.iloc[:, 54:61].values.astype(float)
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '384,870.3'

There is something that I might have missed out either in my code I should have added something earlier at my readexcel during the import but I don't know how to do it.

I looked up on dtype argument for readexcel but couldn't find an example on how to declare a specific range of columns to convert to int during import. The example that I found is like the below:

```
pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx', index_col=0, dtype={'Name': str, 'Value': float})
```

My data has too many years created as columns to declare individually, is there a way out?

My desired numpy array output after conversion is below (not [ '69124.4' ....]) :

```
[  69124.4   63585.4   51331.7  174596.4  183850.7 -107672.4   49833.8
  120578.6   40884.1  106405.   126586.1   94867.2   22184.3  100575.9
  110966.1   52548.9  243641.7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
df_gdp.iloc[1:, 1] = df_gdp.iloc[1:, 0].str.replace("'", "").astype(float)
```

You must use:

```
lst = df_gdp.iloc[0,1:].to_list()
lst = [s.replace(',', '') for s in lst]
lst = [float(i) for i in lst]
```

Now lst is: `[69124.4   63585.4   51331.7  174596.4 , ...]`

Works fine for:

[image]

Comment: Hi Meysam, I have tried your code but it doesn't work. the excel file is in.xlsx and that portion on replace(",", "") is replacing the delimiter comma with blank space, is that right? The value in the dataframe is still shown as string '384,870.3'

Comment: Nope, the program returns 
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Series([])'